# django-ckeditor: ckeditor js file not included

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm trying to use the ckeditor package from here: https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor . I have followed the directions, but I can't seem to figure out what the path is to include the ckeditor.js file.

Every time I go to a page with the ckeditor widget/field I get a javascript error because of this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

I did run collectstatic etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for serving static files.

If you're in development and using `runserver` you'll want to add the following to your url conf -

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

See this section of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) specifically.